# How do you handle idempotency in multi-region Lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, idempotent

I have a Lambda sat behind an API Gateway. This Lambda receives API requests which have to be processed **exactly once**.

When the Lambda receives a request, it stores the request's `IdempotencyKey` to DynamoDB - [as per AWS best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-idempotent/). The `PUT` to DynamoDB uses [a conditional insert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites) (i.e.  `--condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(IdempotencyKey)"`), so if the `IdempotencyKey` is found on the table, the `PUT` request returns a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`, and the Lambda responds gracefully.

If the `IdempotencyKey` is successfully inserted into the table, we propagate the request payload downstream using an SQS FIFO queue ([since it supports exactly once processing, so it's an additional layer of idempotency protection if we send two messages with the same payload within 5 minutes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-exactly-once-processing.html))

The problem is scaling this to a multi-region deployment:

- We can upgrade the DynamoDB table to a Global Table, but AWS documentation says "[a newly written item is **usually** propagated to all replica tables **within a second**](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/)"

  - If we receive the same request twice **in under a second**, and each request goes to a different region, I assume this means that the Lambda in each region could successfully insert the data into DynamoDB - since the inserted data from the other region may not have propagated yet.
  - I assume that they say "**usually** propagated to all replica tables within a second" because outages may result in database partitions.
- If we have an SQS FIFO queue in each region - e.g. `us-east-1` and `us-west-2` - the queue in `us-east-1` won't know if a message passed to it has already been passed to the queue in `us-west-2` - at which point they can no longer be used for ensuring **exactly once** processing.

How do I scale this idempotency checking/exactly once processing to a multi-region architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is on-topic for SO or not...

But just to throw an idea out there...

If your lambda is in us-east-1 and us-west-2, consider having your DDB in us-east-2 and us-west-1.

Now configure the lambda's to both write to the DDB in a single region, unless that region is down at which point both lambda's write to DDB in the backup region.